# Email icon and headers for Inbox by Gmail

Tags: gmail, html-email

I use Inbox for Gmail. Recently, I came across emails that had little custom summaries in Inbox. These are auto generated headers for emails from Quartz.com.

I couldn't find documentation on this. How can I add auto-summary headers to emails?

This is how the email from Quartz looks in Gmail Inbox:
[image: This is how Quartz looks in Gmail Inbox]

This is how the email message looks when opened:
[image: This is how the email message looks when opened]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These emails in Google Inbox are known as [glanceable newsletters](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2016/04/inbox-by-gmail-better-way-to-keep-track.html). At the time of this answer, this is enabled for only a few email senders. So for the time being, the rest of us are out of luck.

In the meantime, we can start marking up our emails in anticipation of this feature eventually being enabled for the masses. It's not 100% clear how Google is building out these previews, but they provide [some related documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/article#use_cases) on email coding guidelines. We can also use [schema markup](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/) to specify what's what in an email so Google (or whoever else) can intelligently build previews. The best rundown I've seen so far is [on Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/inbox-by-gmail-update-what-you-need-to-know-about-glanceable-newsletters).

But for the time being, other than setting a Google+ profile picture, there's not much we can do except wait for Google to roll this out further.

Comment: Thank you. That answers a lot of questions. How about the little icons in the Inbox?